# The button changing to loading in Firefox does not work

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I created a simple button that changes to load after clicking. Should validate the form. The code looks like this:

```
  <button type="submit" onClick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value='acceptAction'; buttonSubmit();" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="acceptAction">
    <span style="display:block;" id="buttonText">
      Next step <i class="fas fa-chevron-right ml-2"></i>
    </span>
    <span style="display:none;" id="buttonSipner">
      Loading...
      <div class="spinner-border spinner-grow-sm ml-2" role="status">
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
      </div>
    </span>
  </button>

  <!-- JS Page -->
  <script>
  function buttonSubmit() {
  document.getElementById('buttonText').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('buttonSipner').style.display = 'block';
  }
  </script>
```

The problem is that when the button is clicked on Firefox, if the form is not filled in it locks up and nothing more can be done. This does not work only on Firefox (73.0.1 x64 en-US). Other browsers will check the form and unlock the button.

[image]

Comment: What does it means *"the form is not filled"*? Where is your form validation code? PS `Sipner` like spine or rather *spinner* like spinning? ;)

Comment: Also, why do you use a **placeholder** for `Manual transmission` ? Why not use rather Manual transmission as a default value or rather a disabled option like `--Select a transmission type--`??

Comment: This means that the field is simply left blank.My validation code is implemented on the server side. However, it does not go to the server. I see the message "Please fill out this field". Other browsers allow field to server. Firefox doesn't.

Comment: In Firefox *right-click* on the form field element that says is not being filled out and press the `Q` key to "quickly inspect". That usually happens when there is a `required="true"` (or `required="required"`) attribute/value on that element. If there isn't look for an event listener either on the element (`ev` at the right on an element in the Developer Inspector tools (`Q`)) or on the parent `form` element. Also it seems you didn't post the code for the element in question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For the form to work, you had to change submit to button

Works well:

```
<button type="button" [...] >Submit</button>
```

Does not work:

```
<button type="submit" [...] >Submit</button>
```

Only on Firefox was required.